# Delete from a JPARepository with an EmbeddedId by a field in the primary key

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, crud-repository

Currently I have a Spring Boot application using JpaRepository<Employee, EmployeePk>
where let's say EmployeePk is firstname, lastname. Is there a way to delete by Primary Key field without having to specify a custom @Query? It's ok to delete multiple rows if multiple people were named "John".

Example:

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, EmployeePk> {

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "DELETE FROM Employee e WHERE e.EmployeePk.firstname = :firstname ")
    void deleteAllByEeId(String firstname);
}
```

such as

```
void deleteByEmployeePkWhereFirstname(String firstname);
```

Employee class and Embedded PK

```
public class Employee {

    @EmbeddedId
    private EmployeePK employeePK;
    
    private LocalDate birthDate;

}

public class EmployeePK implements Serializable {

    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;
}
```

Comment: can you post the code of the entiy Employee and the class EmployyPk ? In fact you can use methods defined by `JpaRepository` based in the entity fields to delete employees by firstName

Comment: Posted. Yes I was looking for something like you mentioned but couldn't find documentation when it involved an EmbeddedId.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for adding the Employee and EmployeePK code source.

Since you have the field `firstName` in your entity so you can *use derived delete queries that let you avoid having to declare the JPQL query explicitly*

Based in [spring data documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries)

> Derived Delete Queries
>
> Spring Data JPA also supports derived delete queries that let you
> avoid having to declare the JPQL query explicitly, as shown in the
> following example:

You can add this method in your repositroy.

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, EmployeePK> {

void deleteByEmployeePK_FirstName(String firstName);
}
```

You don't need `@Modify` annotation since you will not use `@Query` annotation.

And add `@Entity` to your entity in order to be mapped by the associated table in the database.

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

@EmbeddedId
private EmployeePK employeePK;

private LocalDate birthDate;

 }
```

Comment: That works. Thank you Abenamor!

Comment: Great :) can you accept it as a response for your post :)

Comment: What's the difference between deleteByEmployeePK_FirstName and deleteByEmployeePKFirstName (no underscore)? I see that both are valid syntax.

EDIT: I see the answer below states it's just readability

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```java
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, EmployeePk> {

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    void deleteByEmployeePKFirstName(String firstname);
}
```

Or if you want it to be more readable:

```java
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, EmployeePk> {

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    void deleteByEmployeePK_FirstName(String firstname);
}
```

Comment: Works. Thank you!

Comment: If my answer helped you consider upvoting it and even accepting it as the answer so that it can be ”closed” and others can benefit from it and easily understand which could be a possible solution for similar questions ;) Thanks!

Comment: Oh, you accepted already another answer. That is ok but consider at least upvoting mine. Thanks!

Comment: Definitely! I just made this account and finally got enough points to upvote other users. Also wish I could accept both as solutions.

Comment: Thanks @Bizzaroerik!